# "they got married" vs "they have got married"

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions

Is

> They got married

the same as

> They have got married

Is word "have" is ommited from the first sentence? But both have the same meaning. If not, why is *got* used with an adjective "married"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`married` is not an adjective but a past participle. Your verb is `to get married`.

The difference between the sentences is that the verb is at different tenses. First is at **past tense simple**, the second one is at **present perfect simple**.

- Past tense simple is used to describe past actions where the time has
  been specified.

  `They got married yesterday. They got married last year.`
- Present perfect simple is used to describe past actions where the
  time has not been specified.

  `They have got married.` but we don't know when

Comment: I would never say "they have got married", _gotten_ would be my word choice

Comment: both `got` and `gotten` are accepted as the 3rd form of the verb `get`

Comment: @Deolater There is no such word as *gotten* in UK English, only *got*. In US English, both are acceptable.